# Installing ODAC for .NET

Tags: odac

I have Visual Studio .NET 2008 in my [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) machine.
I have the [Oracle 10g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Releases_and_versions) client.

As one of my applications uses ODAC, I need to install ODAC now. The latest version of ODAC is ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.

As I already have the *C:\Oracle* folder if I install this ODAC again, it installs one more *oracle_home* folder which I don’t need.

How can I install it?

Comment: I don't understand the problem... either you want the new/additional ODAC version or not... if you want/need it then it comes with an Oracle home...

Comment: I need the new ODAC. My question is that if there is any other way of installing without have to have two different Oracle homes.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to install the version of the Oracle client that the ODAC wants.  You also have to decide between 32 bit and 64 bit.

One caution if you are new to Oracle and .NET, you will have to install the oracle client on the server and that creates a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

ODAC doesn't install an Oracle client on the machine. ODAC will use the Oracle client to communicate with Database Server, so no it won't create a new *oracle_home* folder.